# HP MFP M225Dn can print but cannot scan - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, hp, scanner, sane

I'm trying to set up a HP MFP M225Dn multifunction printer/scanner on a local network with 3 Linux PCs (one with 16.04, one with 14.04, one with Mint 17.3 - based on 14.04).
Printing was o.k. on 16.04, no need to install anything, while I needed to update HPLIP on 14.04 and Mint to get them print, so now PRINTING IS OK for all PCs.

Scanner has been a little harder to install on 16.04, while I haven't been able to make it work on both 14.04 and Mint at all.
On both issued PCs, running `xsane` I got `no devices available`, the same using `sudo xsane`.

I think it can be a `sane-backend` problem. None of these "recent" HP MFP printers appear in the supported list, [see http://www.sane-project.org](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html), despite it works on 16.04.

I'm looking for suggestions. What can I look for on 16.04 that can help me making it work on 14.04 too?

**EDIT**

As suggested I'm adding some outputs:

1. `$ sane-config --version` returns `1.0.23`
2. `$ xsane` (v. 0.998) outputs a window saying "no devices available"
3. `$ scanimage
   scanimage: no SANE devices found`
4. `$ sane-find-scanner`:

   ```
   # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
   # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
   # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

   # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
   # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

   # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
   # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
   # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

   # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

   # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
   # can't be detected by this program.
   ```

BTW: of course the scanner is turned on.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may be a `sane` backend problem but it's rather unlikely. To troubleshoot this with you for 14.04, please post full answer to my questions in edits of OP, not as further comments. Scanner printer must be switched on at all times. -- 1) What is yr version of libsane on 14.04 ? -- Open terminal. What happens when you: 2) type: $ xsane ? -- 3) type `$ scanimage` ? -- 4) type `$ sane-find-scanner` ? -- More after yr 4 replies. Let me know when you've edited yr OP, just by writing @Cbhihe in a comment.

Comment: @Cbhihe thanx, i added some outputs

Comment: If you cannot get it working with SANE -- though I hope you can!!! -- there is a proprietary (paid) software package called VueScan that usually makes scanners "just work" in Linux: https://www.hamrick.com/ Again, I hope you can get it working under SANE, but I want to mention this option in case you run out of ideas

Comment: @NickWeinberg: No need for commercial $tuff. We should get it to work on FOSS. It's just a bit of a process to get there....

Comment: Nb 1 consistent with 14.04 distro roll-out version. Nbr 4 not useful (my bad) because I ignored the fact that scanner is networked and `sane-find-scanner` handles USB & SCSI scanners only. -- For MFP scanners, add `saned` to group `lp` and `scanner` with `$ sudo adduser saned {scanner,lp}` -- Ensure package `libsane-extras` is installed. Yr `universe` repo must be enabled. -- Edit `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`. Enable correct scan-driver by looking for "The following backends are not part of the SANE distr..." Uncomment 1 line at a time where deemed appropriate, save and run `$ xsane`. -- Edit OP.

Comment: Feed back on the answer offered below ? Did you pursue this topic at all ? Cheers. ;-)

Comment: I was just typing a comment to your beautiful "guide", but formally i think cannot accept it (can i?) because i solved in a different way, see my comment to your answer. Many thanx again!

Answer (score 3):

I provide you with a generic answer, short of being able to thoroughly troubleshoot yr issue. Being generic the answer is long.

***Assuming*** that:

- yr networked scanner is switched on.
- yr device is connected to:
  **a)** *the network as a stand alone LAN device* (direct LAN-setup).
  **b)** *a computer and shared over the network*: that computer is referred to as the LAN-server. All other networked computers are called LAN-clients. Setting this up differs from what follows. That case is not covered here.
- packages `hplip`, `sane-utils`, `libsane` as well as `libsane-extras` are correctly installed. The latter requires the `universe` repo to be enabled.
- you have added user `saned` to groups `lp` ***and*** `scanner` with:

In terminal

```
$ sudo adduser saned {scanner,lp}
```

In reality only one of those two groups (`lp`, `scanner`) is needed, but you can safely add `saned` to both. It won't hurt. HP scanners of type MFP tend to be added to `lp`, others to `scanner`. This is required when scanning from a USB connected all-in-one shared on the network, i.e. through a scan-server. I have not verified that it is required for stand-alone LAN scanners. Again if not, it won't hurt.

- you have edited `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`, to try to enable the correct scan-driver for yr device. Try looking for "The following backends are not part of the SANE distribution ..." in that configuration file. Below that you'll find commented lines corresponding to scanners that are either not directly supported (untested) or partially supported. Uncomment lines as you deem appropriate, save file.

From the Ubuntu community's [Scanning-HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo):

- Ensure the device can be pinged.
- Run the hp-setup wizard which installs printer, scanner, [HpAllInOne](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne) and any other features.

In terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-qt4  # required only for Ubuntu 14.04
$ sudo hp-setup
```

For Connection Type choose "Network/Ethernet..."
If the device is not detected, click "Show advanced options", tick "Manual discovery" and supply the scanner's IP address.
 
Check the scanner is now recognized:

```
$ scanimage -L
```

Alas, if yr scanning device is still not detected:

- Determine the URI of the printer

Inside a terminal window, execute:

```
 $ hp-makeuri IP-ADDRESS
```

where "IP-ADDRESS" should be replaced with the IP address of your *printer*. This will show the CUPS (printing) and SANE (scanning) URIs for your printer.

- Access yr networked scanner (two approaches):

**a)** temporarily access scanner by supplying  the SANE URI to `xsane` every time you execute it:

```
$ xsane SANE-URI
```

where "SANE-URI" is the SANE URI returned by `hp-makeuri`.

**b)** make scanner permanently accessible, if CUPS is configured to use the 'hp' backend to access the printer instead of the 'socket' backend. This can be done by editing `printers.conf`:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

and replacing the 'socket' DeviceURI with the 'hp' URI returned by hp-makeuri. Restart cups after making this change:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cupsys restart
```

HTH. Please, report details if this does not work for you, but remember that [StartPage](https://www.startpage.com/) is yr friend.

Comment: Well, many many thanx, really exhaustive answer. In facts i had bigger problems (my hd started crashing last week, i had to reinstall and i chose 16.04). Anyway your "guide" helped me setting up the scanner on Mint 17.3, basically there was a cheksum error on a plug-in, i solved following this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1476011. Thanx again!

Comment: @j.c: Good. I am glad I could be of some help. I just saw the bug report. Good workaround. Cheers ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using HPLIP from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing

It works like a charm on any Ubuntu version.
Scanner works as well.

Comment: if hplip does not help, check also my answer which solves issue with hplip

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the topic having the issue myself, tried tips here to no avail.

What was the issue at my end was having SNMPv1/v2 disabled completely at Printer's settings.

After I have enabled SNMPv1/v2 for Read Only access, scanner was discovered without any issues and works like a charm.

Hope my issue will help someone some day.

Additional note:
This particular solution might be applicable to all operating systems having issues with HP MFP devices and scanning functions.